# How do I create a dropdown with multiple state and city selections?

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, flutter-dependencies

I'm working on a Flutter project, and I need to implement a drop-down menu that allows users to select both a state and a city.

Essentially, I want the dropdown to have two levels:

- The first level should display a list of states, and upon selecting a state,
- The second level should dynamically populate with the cities within that state.

[image: Demo Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this package [multiselect_nested](https://pub.dev/packages/multiselect_nested)

Here is an example code for it and it's working as you expected.[image]

```
List<MultiSelectNestedItem> selected = [];
MultiSelectNestedController multiSelectController = MultiSelectNestedController();

Future<List<MultiSelectNestedItem>> getJson() async {
    var data = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/example_data.json');
    return multiSelectItemsFromJson(data);
}
  
FutureBuilder<List<MultiSelectNestedItem>>(
    future: getJson(),
    builder: (BuildContext context,
      AsyncSnapshot<List<MultiSelectNestedItem>> snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return const Text('Loading....');
      default:
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        } else {
          return Column(
            children: [
              MultiSelectNested(
                controller: multiSelectController,
                options: snapshot.data!,
                selectedValues: selected,
                setSelectedValues:
                    (List<MultiSelectNestedItem> newValues) {
                  setState(() {
                    selected = newValues;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        }
    }
  },
),
```